# Как вернуть ячейку выше найденной ячейки с помощью openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Я произвожу поиск в некоторой таблице и нахожу нужную мне ячейку. Мне нужно вывести значение ячейки на одну ячейку выше найденной мной. С помощью какого метода это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [cell.offset(row=-1)](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html)